# Iterate Python list discontinuously and irregularly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In case we have a list `[1,2,3,...,N]` (length equal to `N`). Then we are going to print the `[2:-2]` and the last item in the list. What should we do?

Furthermore, what if we make things more irregular? Like we are going to print the `[2:5]`, `[7:N-10]`, `[-3:]` items in the list?

For example:

```
Lines=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....N-1,N]

for line in Lines[what should I input here?]:

   print(line)
```

and the output:

```
1
2
4
5
6
N-5
N-2
N-1
N
```

(By giving this stupid output, I'm just trying to make things discontinuously and irregularly)

We should finish the code in one function. We don't want codes like:

```
def fun():
  for line in Lines[2:-2]:print(i)
  print(Lines[-1])
```

We looking forward some code like list comprehension, e.g. (this is wrong, I'm just using it to express the idea):

```
for line in Lines[x for x in range(2,10) and 12]
```

Comment: say an element comes up in two of the slice, do you want to print it once or twice?

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. If you have attempted to implement this and had a specific problem, show a [mcve] **of that**. If you have **working code** you would like feedback on, see [codereview.se].

Comment: Twice. Thank you. We are trying to make code elegant

Comment: Hope I have made question clearly. We think this is a useful question because you can change the print( i ) function to something else. People can learn how to operate each item in list as they want.

Comment: So where is your implementation? *"what should I input here?"* does not count as an attempt. *"We should finish the code in one function"* - that's right, **you should**.

Comment: 'what should i input here?' is the answer this question is asking...Since we don't know what to input...We think there maybe some elegant code to input here and get the output

Comment: There may be, but SO is **still not a code-writing service**. Maybe start with some *in*elegant code and try to improve it from there? I'd imagine you're being set this task in the hope that you might learn something, not just outsource the implementation to somebody else.

Comment: All of that is irrelevant: SO isn't here to write code for you. If you want people to write code for you, hire contractors. I'm sorry that Mike has seen fit to do that anyway, I understand that's confusing to new users. Maybe take the [tour] and review the [help] before asking additional questions?

Comment: Thank you, I feel shamed and I will read the tour before any more questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create each line in a generator expression:

```
from itertools import chain

lines = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for line in (lines[index] for index in chain(range(0, 6, 2), range(5, 6))):
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
6
```

Comment: Yeah you are working on the index of the list, that's smart!

Comment: Yes,thank you. We  just focus on items in list and missed the point that we can do something on the index of item